# How do I remove routes in an ActiveAdmin Resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I've created an ActiveAdmin resource, but I would prefer that admins cannot delete or create new records, only view and edit. How do I remove the other routes from the Active Admin resource?

Answer (score 3):

```
ActiveAdmin.register Model do
  actions :index, :show, :edit, :update
end
```

This will remove `create`, `new` and `destroy` from the controller.

Comment: This answer gave me an error:
```lib/active_admin/resource_dsl.rb:114:in `action': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2..3) (ArgumentError)```

Comment: @JosephFakelastname Looks like you're using `action` instead of `actions`.